# -D name=definition and bitwise operator

Tags: c, gcc, bitwise-operators, bitflags

I am trying to understand how the next calculation is performed.

For example, if this is my terminal command

```
gcc ex2.c -D b+=2
```

Why do I get 5?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
#ifdef b
    printf("%d\n", 2 b | ~ 2 b);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

2 b mean 2*b ?

~ 2 b  mean 2*b and then ~ ?

Comment: This is ...weird....don't learn to write and execute code like this.

Comment: This is a question from a test that I did

Comment: According to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) `-D b+=2` doesn't seem like a valid syntax.

Comment: I guess whoever gave the test is into Shakespeare ("2 b | ~ 2 b" is C for "to be, or not to be"). Fun, but also a bit annoying in a learning context, this is very contrived and in the real world programmers doing things like this are at high risk of getting ... words in a code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compiling with `gcc ex2.c -D b+=2` define *b* as `+2` so the source

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
#ifdef b
    printf("%d\n", 2 b | ~ 2 b);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

is like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("%d\n", 2 + 2 | ~ 2 + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

and for me that prints `-1`

---

to see the result after the preprocessing use the option -E :

```
/tmp % gcc ex2.c -E -D b+=2
<command-line>: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
...
# 2 "ex2.c" 2

int main()
{

    printf("%d\n", 2 + 2 | ~ 2 + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so the ' ~ ' operator  is on 2 or 2+2 ?

Comment: @GiladRozmarin it is on _2_ because of the operator precedence, in both case the result is -1 because put all the bits to 1

Comment: it was by mistake

Comment: @GiladRozmarin do not forget the option `-E` it is useful to understand what appends, you can put in comment some #include before to use it to not have plenty lines produced

Answer (score 7):

This is weird that it works and looks like a bug (or feature) from `gcc` and `clang` in parsing command line arguments.

Looks like `gcc` substitutes the first `=` sign in macro declaration by a space. So the parameter:

```
-D b+=2
```

is equal to

```
#define b+ 2
```

which because `gcc` has an extension to interpret it like that, it is equal to

```
#define b + 2
```

which makes the preprocessor output:

```
printf("%d\n", 2 + 2 | ~ 2 + 2);
```

the expression `2 + 2 | ~ 2 + 2` is equal to `(2 + 2) | ((~ 2) + 2)` (see [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)) which on [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system is equal to `4 | (-3 + 2)` which is equal to `4 | -1`. On twos-complement `-1` is equal to `0xff....ff` so `4 | -1` is equal to `0xff...ff` (as it is binary OR) which is `-1`.

Comment: so for b+=3  i will get 5 ?

Comment: No idea, let's see: `2 + 3 | ~ 2 + 3` = `5 | -3 + 3` = `5 | 0` = `5`. Yea, you will get lucky `5`.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend

Comment: This is really ugly. It also works with more complicated expressions, like `printf 'b\nb b\nb(3)' | gcc -E - -dD -D'b(=x)(x+x)'`. I hope no one uses this for practical programming, and I haven't even seen an IOCCC entry misusing this.

Comment: I found [the GCC code doing this, in cpp_define](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e1b6ccb9e6bf0bf18f0b4154e16d3c5cdfab305e/libcpp/directives.c#L2377), it's exactly what you assumed. I didn't find a test case for this behavior though.

Comment: And [the code for LLVM](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/e88e2b99353fe50f7bcfe83436883a72f9fb8c54/clang/lib/Frontend/InitPreprocessor.cpp#L38). Also no mention about the feature misused in this question.